# LINQ Join fails because of type mismatch

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

I need data from 2 different databases. I have tried the following

```
var User = (from U in _db.TblUsers
                        where U.IsAdmin == false
                        select U).ToList();

var AspNewsUser = (from A in _dbAspNet.aspnet_Users                        
                   select A).ToList();


var result = (from U in User
              join A in AspNewsUser
              on U.UserID equals A.UserId
              select U);
```

But I get the following error message

> *The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.*

Comment: In both collections UserId has different types. Check this first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [table schema of aspnet_Users](http://www.adivo.com/samples/database/aspnetdb/TB-ASPNETDB-aspnet_Users.htm), `Userid` is a [`uniqueidentifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942.aspx) (maps to GUID in entity framework). I bet that `TblUsers.UserID` has a different type (like `int`).

Answer (score 0):

Use projection, make them the same anonymous type.

```
    var Users = (from U in _db.TblUsers
                    where U.IsAdmin == false
                    select new { UserID = U.UserID }).ToList();

    var AspNewsUsers = (from A in _dbAspNet.aspnet_Users                        
                    select new { UserID = A.UserID }).ToList();


    var result = (from i in Users join o in AspNewUsers on i.UserID equals o.UserID).ToList();
```